# pull json array from php page with swift

Tags: php, swift, xcode, nsurlsessiondatatask

I have a php page that returns a JSON array, here is the php:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM SongTable";
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
   $allarray[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($allarray, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

In my swift code I want to use `datataskwithURL` to download the JSON array, then save that data to a new array to use later. Here is my swift code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //Data Pull Section
    let url_to_request = (string: "********")
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: url_to_request)!
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)

    //request data from URL
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        (
        data, response, error) in

        guard let _:NSData = data as NSData?, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }
        //create data string
        let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print(dataString! as NSString)

    }
} //close viewDidLoad
```

When I run the Simulator in Xcode I don't get any errors, But I don't know how to make sure its working properly or not.  I also Need to save this data I am getting from the url to a new array in xcode.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do not use examples from kaleidosblog, they're horrible. Find other tutorials.

Comment: yeah I ended up marking this one has a failed attempt!!